# change of directory is very slow

Tags: fedora, zsh, performance, git, cd-command

from time to time changing to a directory (through terminal) launches **git** process which takes **100%** of CPU time and up to 5-6 seconds during which my console is absolutely unresponsive.

This doesn't happen every time when I navigate to this directory, but it happens several times during the day.

After 5-7 seconds **git** process is gone and I get into the directory

Any ideas?

my **~.zshrc** is [here](https://gist.github.com/dmitry-saritasa/2fdf982cb6663d212a756af410e30006)

```
➜  Config git:(develop) uname -a         
Linux dmitry 4.13.4-200.fc26.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 28 20:46:39 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  Config git:(develop) zsh --version    
zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
➜  Config git:(develop) 
➜  Config git:(develop) bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Your zsh/git configurations are going to be critical to diagnosing this.

Comment: Are you using some git command to set (parts of) your shell prompt?

Comment: I have added .zshrc config.  I'm using antigen to load modules and display status info in the prompt. It gets some info from git, but I have no custom invocation of git by my own code. It just started to happen last week and infrequently. Like 2-3 times a day.

Comment: Is this directory on a local disk or some network share?

Comment: Local, ssd disks @AndyDalton

Comment: Does this happen for every directory at random, or just some directories?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what precmd, chpwd hooks are defined in your environment, and your prompts. If you run `set -x` (maybe with a `PS4='+[%D{%T.%.}] %N:%i> '`), you may be able to see what those hooks try to do that take time.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably have to debug it yourself as your ~/.zshrc is very specific and uses many third party extensions.

Some debugging tools that will help you here:

- `PS4='+[%D{%T.%.}] %N:%i> ' zsh -x`

  and try to reproduce the problem.

  That will log all commands run by zsh with some timing so you can identify which one takes a lot of time and what is calling it.

  You may want to  run that under `script` (see also its `-t` option) or with `2> file.log` as the output is likely to be very copious.
- `strace -tte execve -s 999 -o strace.log zsh`

  That traces all command executions again with timing.

You could also instrument calls to `git` only with something like:

```
git() {
  local PS4='[%D{%T.%.}] %N:%i:'
  print -u2 -f '-> %s (%s)\n' ${funcstack:^funcfiletrace}
  set -o localoptions -o xtrace
  command git "$@"
}
```